# react-router Navigate component in Nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

How can i achieve a similar result just like `Navigate` component of react-router has, in Nextjs?
There is a next/Router option but i want to return something to navigate.

i want to redirect the page, but not with `router.push` because i have to use a `useEffect` but i only want to know if there is a way to do the exact same thing using returning a component

Basically what is the equivalent of this in Nextjs without react-router

```js
import { Navigate } from "react-router";

const Page = () => {
  const { user } = useAuth();

  if (user?.role.name === "user") {
    return <Navigate to={"/app"} />;
  } else {
    return <Navigate to={"/app/workspaces"} />;
  }
}

export default Page
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(New Next.js 13.4 App Router approach)**

My implementation is just a simplified version of the [React Router's `<Navigate/>` component](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/packages/react-router/lib/components.tsx#L201). As [noted](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/upgrading/v5#use-usenavigate-instead-of-usehistory) in the React Router doc, "the v6 `<Navigate />` uses **`push` logic by default** and you may change it via `replace` prop". So the default value for `replace` in my implementation will be `false` just for API consistency.

```
import {useRouter} from 'next/navigation'
import {useEffect} from 'react'

type NavigateProps = {to: string; replace?: boolean}

export default function Navigate({to, replace = false}: NavigateProps): null {
  const router = useRouter()

  useEffect(() => {
    if (replace) {
      router.replace(to)
    } else {
      router.push(to)
    }
  }, [replace, router, to])

  return null
}
```

And you might consume it at the root layout that wraps all the routes and pages you want to protect (e.g. `/protected/*` routes):

```
// /app/protected/layout.tsx
'use client'

import {useAuth} from '@scope/react-auth'
import {Fragment, ReactNode} from 'react'
import Navigate from '~/components/Navigate'

export default function Layout({children}: {children: ReactNode}) {
  return <RequireLogin>{children}</RequireLogin>
}

function RequireLogin({children}: {children: ReactNode}) {
  const {currentUser} = useAuth()

  return <Fragment>{currentUser ? children : <Navigate to="/ap/login" replace />}</Fragment>
}
```

⚠️ According to one of the authors of react-router, using `render` prop for private routes [should be avoided in React Router v6](https://gist.github.com/mjackson/d54b40a094277b7afdd6b81f51a0393f).

⚠️ According to the [new `useRouter()` API](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-router), the new `useRouter` hook should be imported from `next/navigation` and not `next/router`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use router.replace if u dont wwant to push but it will have a flaw that it will overwrite the current route

```
router.replace(url, as, options)
```

Answer (score 0):

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router

```
router.push(url, as, options)
```

Is that what you mean?

Comment: No, i want to redirect the page, but not with `router.push` because i have to use a `useEffect` but i only want to know if there is a way to do the exact same thing using returning a component